# how to navigate between pages using phantomjs

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs

I want to navigate between pages inside the same `page.open(url, function(status) { }` using only **phantomjs**. Is that possible?

Example:

```
page.open(url, function(status) {
    page.includeJs("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.slim.min.js", function() {
        var response = page.evaluate(function() {

            ..code..

            window.location.replace('new url');

            ..code for new url..

            return response;

         });

        console.log(response);

        phantom.exit();

    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure out that the best option to do that is use casperjs.

[casperjs.org](http://casperjs.org)